# KVM : Add extra memory from the host's swap

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm

I am running a KVM virtual machine on a host that has 6 Gb of memory and around 15 Gb of swap, so the max of the memory that i can add to the guest is < 6 Gb.
I am wondering, is there a way to add more than 6 GB to the guest, as in my case, it needs more than 10 Gb.

One more thing, the swap in the guest needs to be disabled.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello Al Mahdi Chihaoui. Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: Hi, when i try to increase the maximum allocation and the current allocation, it get reset to the maximum that my host have which is in my case 4096 MB. The application that i am running in the guest need more than 8 GB of RAM, and also, the part that i forgot to mention, the swap in the guest need to be disabled.

Comment: Please add that to your question. There's no need to say you forgot to mention anything - just [put it in your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/471035/edit).